How to set a custom texture for a wall (Ped Library)
I was wondering if it was possible to import or use different textures outside of the default Anylogic selections. In particular, I wanted to import a chain-link fence texture for a wall. Looking at the Anylogic help page, there is the setColor() function, but I am unsure how I could use (not a huge coding-whiz) it to reference an uploaded or external texture downloaded off the internet.
My current solution was to just import a 3D object of a chain-link fence which works in the meantime, but I'd rather use the wall markup tool to save headache with scaling them to look better.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From my understanding, you can't import your own textures to add to the wall.

When you add a texture to the wall, you are using the Texture class in AnyLogic which has a set of predefined textures.
Unfortunately, this class doesn't have a visible constructor and it doesn't have a function to use your own texture file.
So I think it's not possible to do it. If you want a chain link fence, you need to import your own 3D object with the texture you want.
